# How can I reply to email by sending a delivery failure message?

Tags: software-recommendation, email, automation

Occasionally, I receive unwanted emails, particularly low-volume spam, or email messages falsely addressed to me (possibly due to typos). I don't want to spend the energy to write a personal message, but I do want to let the sender know that the message never arrived at its destination, and that resending it will be useless. In my opinion, a delivery error message to the sender will fill that need. So, the question is if there is an easy way to send error messages back to the sender.

Is there any email client out there which supports sending delivery failure messages as a reply to incoming email -- ideally in one click? (Or, which can be configured to do so?)

Alternatively, what is the best way to set up an environment that allows me to send delivery failure messages without too much effort per message sent?

Comment: Not trying to start a discussion, but I'm pretty sure spammers don't care about delivery failure messages.

Answer (score -1):

1) Spammers don't care about delivery failure messages, and sometimes by sending them you can be unintentionally spamming someone else due to the ability to forge the Reply-To field.

2) The type of delivery failure notification you're likely thinking about is generated when the server receives the email, if it reaches your inbox it's come too far. Aside from you sending your own custom "I did not receive this message" response..

Comment: You are right, it won't work for mass spammers with fake "From" headers, but it will work for senders of other messages which find their way into my mailbox. It's a way of saying: "whoever you are looking for, you'll not find him here." And I prefer a semi-generated error message over a personal message.

Comment: You could just make a form letter explaining the situation and providing a forwarding address, if any.